# Getting a query to work in PHP that works directly in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that runs perfectly if I run it inside of Navicat or phpmyadmin or directly in MySQL, but I can't get it to work when I run it via PHP. Is this a limitation of PHP or perhaps I need to restructure the query. Please advise.

Here is the query in PHP ($supplierAAIAID is defined earlier in the script):

```
$query = <<<eof
SET group_concat_max_len = 100000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(' MAX(IF(`AttributeID` = ''',`AttributeID`,''', `AttributeData`, NULL)) AS `',`AttributeID`,'`')) INTO @sql
FROM `attributes`
WHERE `BrandAAIAID` = '{$supplierAAIAID}' ;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT CONCAT(`PartNumber`,''-'',`BrandAAIAID`) AS `ProductCode`, ', @sql, ' FROM `attributes` WHERE `BrandAAIAID` = ''{$supplierAAIAID}'' GROUP BY `PartNumber` ORDER BY `PartNumber`');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
eof;
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Again, this query works if I run it directly in MySQL or Navicat. I get the following error in PHP, but I don't know what to change.

> Selection Error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SET @sql = NULL;

Comment: You cannot execute multiple queries/statements in one `query()` in PHP. Run them individually, or use `multi_query()`.

Comment: Do I need to run the $result every time I execute the query?

Comment: Lookup multi_query

Comment: Yes, you do, since you need to check for any MySQL related errors before executing the next statement. You may want to consider using a stored procedure for this and call the stored proc from php.

Comment: Thank you all so much. Great advice and crazy fast!

Comment: You are rock stars. It worked like a charm. I had to utilize the data (in this case, I'm exporting to CSV) after the EXECUTE stmt and not after DEALLOCATE...otherwise its an empty set. But your advice got me there. Thank you.